# Localhost - RDS master-master asynchronous data transfer

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, database-replication, rds

I have my web application hosted in localhost as cloudy hosted. Sometimes there is no network connection so I want a solution that makes asynchronous data transfer between cloudy host app and my localhost.

```
i am using
-PHP 7
-RDS
-mysql
-EC2
-Laravel 5.2
```